# Vector Median of Rows in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, median

I have a matrix, of which I would like to calculate the median row-wise, to obtain a vector in which each element is the median of each row. For example {1,2,3;4,5,6} would result in

```
MedianRowWise{1,2,3;4,5,6} = {2;5}
```

The current median formula of Google Sheets instead calculates only one median value for all of the 6 values = 3.5

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0, I gave the example in the first line. If you type in a cell of Google sheets {1,2,3;4,5,6} you obtain an array of two lines and three columns.

Answer (score 1):

these days you can use:

```
=BYROW(A1:C2, LAMBDA(xx, MEDIAN(xx)))
```

[image]

even:

```
=BYROW({1,2,3;4,5,6}, LAMBDA(xx, MEDIAN(xx)))
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks! How long have the BYROW and LAMBDA functions been available in Google sheets?

Comment: @gciriani since 16 September 2022

Answer (score 0):

median row-wise is this formula dragged down:

```
=MEDIAN(A1:C1)
```

[image: .]

---

it could be pre-programmed as (eg. without dragging):

```
={MEDIAN(A1:C1); 
  MEDIAN(A2:C2)}
```

[image: 0]

---

or in some cases you could use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:C), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(A:A, 
 "avg(Col"&ROW(A:A)-ROW(A1)+1&")", ))&"")), 
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Steps:

Apply the formula in cell C1 (refer the screenshot) and then copy and paste it to down. The formula will assign the Median of each group in each and every row.

If you just want to find the Median of each individual groups (there are four groups) as normally, needless to say, you can use the below four formulas.

a. Formula 1

=median(C1:C5)

b. Formula 2

=median(C6:C8)

c. Formula 3

=median(C9:C11)

d. Formula 4

=median(C12:C14)

courtesy: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/median-function-in-google-sheets/

Comment: That's not what I asked, but thank you for trying. My input is an array, not a sequence of groups ordered in a vector. My argument is passed as the result of a filter operation and is an array comprised of m rows and n columns). Thanks again.